# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵcmp') Angular

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular2-aot, angular16, angular-standalone-components

I have created a custom ui library using only standalone components and here's my public-api.ts file.

```
/*
 * Public API Surface of ih-ui-lib
 */

export * from './lib/ui-lib.service';
export * from './lib/ui-lib.component';
export * from './lib/ui-lib.module';

// Exporting components
export * from './lib/components/card/card.component';
export * from './lib/components/card/card-heading/card-heading.component';
export * from './lib/components/card/card-content/card-content.component';
export * from './lib/components/cards-responsive/cards-responsive.component';
export * from './lib/components/collapsible/collapsible.component';
export * from './lib/components/heading/heading.component';
export * from './lib/components/icon/icon.component';
export * from './lib/components/paragraph/paragraph.component';
export * from './lib/components/pill/pill.component';
export * from './lib/components/scrollbar/scrollbar.component';
export * from './lib/components/search/search.component';
export * from './lib/components/search/components/search-column/search-column.component';
export * from './lib/components/search/components/search-row/search-row.component';
export * from './lib/components/status-bar/status-bar.component';
export * from './lib/components/timeline/timeline.component';
```

Here's a example of a component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'card',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.css']
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() classes: string = '';
  @Input() width: string = '';
  @Input() radius: string = 'sm';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Here's how I'm adding to my app's package.json

```
  "ui-library": "git+repo+url.git#branch",
```

I also have index.ts file at the root of my lib which just exports the public-api.ts file so I can access it from the root.

`export * from './dist/ih-ui-lib/public-api';`

I created a new standalone component in my app and tried to import that component into my app.

And that is when I get this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵcmp')

I'm using angular 16.

I tried using modules for components and still it is the same.
I tried importing standalone component to a module in my app and it failed to recognise that component.

Comment: You need to build the library. From the given information it appears you only wrote the source files for the library, but never built it.

Comment: @JSONDerulo I have built the lib, sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: Did you check in the `dist` folder to VCS? It is not recommended to "install" the library via git repository, you should publish the contents of your `dist` folder in a npm registry instead (you can also use a private registry). The problem could be that the `package.json` of your library is in `dist` folder, but the root `package.json` is used which doesn't contain the library.

Comment: hmm, thanks @JSONDerulo
Let me try publishing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build the library and publish the build result as an npm package. From the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#publishing-your-library):

> Use the Angular CLI and the npm package manager to build and publish your library as an npm package.

```
ng build my-lib
cd dist/my-lib
npm publish
```

Installing your library via git repository does not work, because this is just the source code for the library, but you need a built library.

Comment: Publishing or npm linking it works as well for local development

Answer (score 4):

You likely have circular imports which makes it impossible to instantiate the class.

One way to find which one is to use `madge` :

```
npx madge --circular --extensions ts ./
```

Comment: No, that's not the case as the component I'm importing is dynamic and I've only used once on the standalone component I want which is erroring out. 

In the html of the component from ui lib it has ng-content mainly.

Comment: That was my problem :-) That's a really bad error tho, even if you've seen it before it's very non-obvious :-/

Comment: Worked for me, had an injection token defined in the app.component file, and imports in some components caused issues.

Answer (score 1):

We recently encountered a similar problem.
In our case, it helped to use "forwardRef"
in imports `forwardRef(() => "component or directive")`